Integrating Vue.js with Flask and Dash Plotly for Dynamic Data Visualization
I've just joined a project where the entire system is built in Python with Flask and Dash Plotly for creating tables and charts.
The idea is to scale the project in the long term, having a robust authentication system, security standards, and a bot activation and status verification system.
I'm wondering if adding Vue.js as a frontend framework would be a good option. I know Flask and Vue.js work well together, but my question is regarding Dash Plotly.
Can I render charts and tables created with Dash inside Vue.js components? Can I implement some user interactions with Vue.js and have the charts reflect those interactions?
I don't have much experience with Dash, but from what I've read and seen about the tool, I don't believe it's a good fit for maintaining projects of this scale. I could be wrong.

There has been a number of large projects built on Vue.js. Also, there are a number of outdated information about Vue.js, because Vue 3 is very different from Vue 2 (EOL on 2023/12/31).
